# Replace ALL lines of a .txt with first 8 characters having format xx:xx:xx where x is an integer in batch file

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, for-loop, replace

I'm comparing each properties.log file in root dir: c:\executionsdktest_10.2.2 with a reference file. Time of execution in xx:xx:xx format is printed in the first 8 chars of the 28 lines of ref and properties.log file, since the time would be different and inconsequential I would like to skip over first 8 chars of any line containing a time. How can I accomplish this?

```
 REM assume <refLog>.txt exists
<!logPath! (
For /F "tokens=*" %%R in (!refLogPath!) DO (
    set logLine=
        set /p logLine=
    set refLogLine=%%R

    REM Check line by line of log against refLog

    REM if corresponding lines mismatch: skip xx:xx:xx
    if NOT "!logLine!"=="!refLogLine!" (
        Echo.
        Echo line below is Incorrect:
        set lnCorrect=false
        REM output to command line: can be put into .log/.txt later
        REM output ANY and ALL incorrect line in log file
            ECHO !logLine!
                           )
                       )    
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take substrings of variables with

```
!logLine:~8!
```

which would strip the first 8 characters from the line. Likewise for `refLogLine`, of course.

Comment: Hey @Joey I need a more general approach, Everywhere I see xx:xx:xx i would like to skip these 8 characters

Comment: That's quite a bit harder and likely requires plenty of code in a batch file.